# Visual Studio for Mac adding a new Project Item type

Tags: monodevelop, visual-studio-mac, extensibility

The context is that in a Xamarin.Forms project, I want to right-click and add an item from VS in the usual project content menu as maybe an entry called "Add Image Asset", let's say a raster or SVG image, and have it programmatically add those to the resources folder in Android and the Assets.xcassets in the IOS and Mac projects. Maybe it could even size or resize the input image or vector assets to fit into different dpi sizes, which would cut down on a lot of front-end redundancy.

So, an extension would have to be created I would think.

On VS for Windows this isn't such a problem, but be it that the Mac version is Monodevelop-based, is what I want to do even possible, and how?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly this is something that is built-in into [MFractor](https://www.mfractor.com/) so you might want to take a look (you can request a free trial to see how it works). If you are not willing to spend money on such a tool then I believe you can try writing your own extension. This [article](https://medium.com/@jphenow/custom-file-templates-for-visual-studio-mac-f04269d49589) should be a good starting point.

If I were you I would try using MFractor with a trial license so you can decide whether it's worth the money or not. In my opinion, it's a must in XF development (it has so many nice features), but I can understand that there are companies that are not willing to spend money on it. If you are interested you can contact [Matthew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1099111/matthewrdev) for more details.

Comment: I was surprised that MFractor does exactly what I have been setting out to do as far as the images are concerned, when looking through the docs, once you skim past the chapters of docs about purchasing and licenses to get to the helpful parts.

However, I'm on US government medical disability and just simply can't afford MFractor, and even if I could, I would still be curious about VS for Mac extension, as I am now. Most of the code actions and other features of MFractor are "nice to haves" but not necessities for me in development.

Comment: I've partially figured this all out by learning MonoDevelop extensibility, which VS for Mac is based on at its root, I've got at least the content menu items for the image adding dialog. However, I've come across some issues with OpenFileDialog either with Xwt or with MonoDevelop's version that I put here:

https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/issues/7554

Comment: Hey John, was just skimming Stack Overflow (I regularly check it for MFractor hits) and found this. Email me (matthew@mfractor.com) and I'll set you up with a license. More than happy to accommodate for your situation (my little sister is in a similiar position so I can empathise).